# Valid upper value of uniroot function in R

Tags: r

I am writing a simple program to compute the inverse of any probability distribution. For example, in the code snippet below I have used the lognormal distribution.

```
cdf <- function(x){
    plnorm(x, meanlog = 10, sdlog = 1.4, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
    }

root <- function(q){
    uniroot(function(y){cdf(y)-q},lower=0,upper=Inf,extendInt="no",check.conv=FALSE,tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25,maxiter = 1000,trace=0)
    }
```

When I am executing this code and trying to find out the inverse at say probability value root(p), I am getting an error "invalid 'xmax' value".

But when I replace `upper=Inf` by say `upper=100^100` the code is working fine. Please let me know why I cannot use `Inf` as my upper value.

Comment: Because then you get an error?

Comment: @Andrie  True, but it wouldn't have hurt for the package maintainer to explicitly state in the help file that `+/-Inf` are illegal limits.

Answer (score 0):

`uniroot` is a light wrapper around the internal `zeroin2` C function, which enforces finitude of the `lower` and `upper` arguments (and this makes sense when you think about it--how can you optimize over an infinite interval in finite time?):

https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/b28ec999be30efae201f548ed5fb766b5ab9fcb4/src/library/stats/src/optimize.c#L360

Comment: "how can you optimize over an infinite interval in finite time?" --- by using one of a plethora of standard calculus techniques that have existed for centuries.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate drawback of the `uniroot` function.  You can set `upper = .Machine$double.xmax` as a substitute for an upper bound of infinity, and this prevents the function from returning an error, but it then has difficulty finding the root, and will often max out the iterations without finding the root of the function.  It seems that the method has difficulty finding the root of the function unless you can specify a finite interval where the root is not too far towards one end.